# How to configure the Jetty URL rewrite handler?

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty, jetty-9

I'm testing the jetty 9 rewrite feature, trying to rewrite the following URL:

http://localhost/rewrite to http://localhost/test.html

Here is my configuration:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
      <Set name="handler"><Ref refid="oldhandler"/></Set>
      <Set name="rewriteRequestURI"><Property name="jetty.rewrite.rewriteRequestURI" deprecated="rewrite.rewriteRequestURI" default="true"/></Set>
      <Set name="rewritePathInfo"><Property name="jetty.rewrite.rewritePathInfo" deprecated="rewrite.rewritePathInfo" default="false"/></Set>
      <Set name="originalPathAttribute"><Property name="jetty.rewrite.originalPathAttribute" deprecated="rewrite.originalPathAttribute" default="requestedPath"/></Set>

      <!-- Set DispatcherTypes  -->
      <Set name="dispatcherTypes">
        <Array type="javax.servlet.DispatcherType">
          <Item><Call class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" name="valueOf"><Arg>REQUEST</Arg></Call></Item>
          <Item><Call class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" name="valueOf"><Arg>ASYNC</Arg></Call></Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>

      <Call name="addRule">
        <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule">
            <Set name="pattern">/rewrite</Set>
            <Set name="replacement">/test.html</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
      </Call>
    </New>

    ...

</Configure>
```

Opening http://127.0.0.1/test.html in the browser works but http://localhost/rewrite gives me an 404 error.
Did I configure it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to execute:

```sh
java -jar start.jar --add-to-startd=rewrite
```

Modify the `jetty-rewrite.xml` instead of the `jetty.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
   <!-- =========================================================== -->
   <!-- Configure rewrite handler                                   -->
   <!-- =========================================================== -->
   <Call name="insertHandler">
      <Arg>
         <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
            <Set name="rewriteRequestURI">
               <Property name="jetty.rewrite.rewriteRequestURI" deprecated="rewrite.rewriteRequestURI" default="true" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="rewritePathInfo">
               <Property name="jetty.rewrite.rewritePathInfo" deprecated="rewrite.rewritePathInfo" default="false" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="originalPathAttribute">
               <Property name="jetty.rewrite.originalPathAttribute" deprecated="rewrite.originalPathAttribute" default="requestedPath" />
            </Set>
            <!-- Set DispatcherTypes  -->
            <Set name="dispatcherTypes">
               <Array type="javax.servlet.DispatcherType">
                  <Item>
                     <Call class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" name="valueOf">
                        <Arg>REQUEST</Arg>
                     </Call>
                  </Item>
                  <Item>
                     <Call class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" name="valueOf">
                        <Arg>ASYNC</Arg>
                     </Call>
                  </Item>
               </Array>
            </Set>
            <Get id="Rewrite" name="ruleContainer" />
            <!-- see rewrite-compactpath.xml for example how to add a rule -->
            <Call name="addRule">
               <Arg>
                  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule">
                     <Set name="pattern">/rewrite/test.html</Set>
                     <Set name="replacement">/test/test.html</Set>
                  </New>
               </Arg>
            </Call>
         </New>
      </Arg>
   </Call>
</Configure>
```